# MS Office 2016 Build a ribbon using office-js

Tags: office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-2016

I know you can build a full on ribbon using VSTO and COMM plugins. Are you able to build these using the new office-js for MS Word 2016?

I could not find any way to do so. Alternatively, I was wondering if we could build a VSTO plugin ribbon which opens up our office-js plugin?

We just want the ribbon to look nice rather than being in the Insert -> My Add-ins -> as follows:

[image]

Below is what I have following the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/contextual-tabs:

```
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:ov="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>260eddsdd5</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue=" Local"/>
  <Description DefaultValue=" Add-in"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost/dw/assets/icon-80.png"> </IconUrl>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost/dw/assets/icon-80.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>localhost/dw</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Document"/>
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost/dw/taskpane.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="Document">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <GetStarted>
            <Title resid="GetStarted.Title"/>
            <Description resid="GetStarted.Description"/>
            <LearnMoreUrl resid="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl"/>
          </GetStarted>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url"/>
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="PrimaryCommandSurface">
            <CustomTab id="TabCustom1">
              <Group id="myCustomTab.grp1">
                <Label resid="residCustomTabGroupLabel"/>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                </Icon>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="TaskpaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <TaskpaneId>ButtonId1</TaskpaneId>
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <OfficeControl id="Superscript" />
              </Group>
              <OfficeGroup id="Paragraph" />
              <Label resid="customTabLabel1" />
            </CustomTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https:///icon-16.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://icon-32.png"/>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://icon-80.png"/>
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="GetStarted.LearnMoreUrl" DefaultValue="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276812"/>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost/dw/commands.html"/>
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost/dw/taskpane.html"/>
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Title" DefaultValue="Get started !"/>
        <bt:String id="CommandsGroup.Label" DefaultValue="Click"/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Click"/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="GetStarted.Description" DefaultValue=" add-in loaded succesfully. Go to the HOME tab and click the button to get started."/>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Click to Show a Taskpane"/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can customize the ribbon with an Office Web Add-in. Custom buttons and menus on the ribbon are called Add-in Commands and you configure them in the add-in's manifest. For details, start with [Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) and [Create Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands).

Comment: thanks for the message @Rick - I gave a try via the links you sent, but the plugin dissappears completely now. I added what I have on the original question - does that roughly look right for you?  I wonder if it's a version issue

Comment: The article that you linked to is about contextual tabs, which are in preview and not yet supported on Word. Is that what you meant to link to? Can you provide more detail about "plugin dissappears"? What steps reproduce the problem?

Comment: Sorry @Rick I fat fingered something in the manifest - therefore it did not work. Currently it works on Word 2016 (16.0.9029.2016) but does not work on Word 2016 (16.0.5110.100)

Do you have any ideas why that might be?

Comment: According to this page, Add-in Commands are only supported in Outlook in the perpetual license Office 2016, so I'm surprised it works in any perpetual license Word 2016. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/add-in-commands-requirement-sets

Comment: Maybe it's cause of "The add-in commands 1.1 requirement set introduces the ability to autoopen a task pane with documents." Which is what's happening

It also says "The add-in commands 1.3 requirement set introduces manifest markup that enables an add-in to customize the placement of a custom tab on the Office ribbon and to insert built-in Office ribbon controls into custom control groups."